# Elasticsearch query on zip_code failed

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I have a strange behavior on elasticsearch that I cant explain.

When I do :

```
POST /ad_search/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "city_code": "2A247"
    }
  }
}
```

I have multiple result. But when I do (This code is generated by a librairies) :

```
POST /ad_search/_search
{
  "from":0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must":[
        {"term":{"city_code":"2A247"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have no result.

When I search on all other zip_code with only numbers like 71459. The both query are working well and give me the same result.

I was thinking of a mapping problems but it seems ok :

```
GET /ad_search/_mapping
```

```
{
  "ad_search" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "city_code" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Someone have any ideas to unlock me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `city_code` is of type text and thus analyzed, hence what is being indexed is `2a247` (lowercase).

So you can either query `city_code.keyword` with a `term` query, which does an exact match

```
POST /ad_search/_search
{
  "from":0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must":[
        {"term":{"city_code.keyword":"2A247"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Or with a match query on the `city_code` field:

```
POST /ad_search/_search
{
  "from":0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must":[
        {"match":{"city_code":"2A247"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```